# How can I query the contents of a List via LINQ based on string values?

Tags: c#, string, linq, generics, ienumerable

I am trying to query a collection of records using a ">=" for a string column/member.

What I want/am expecting is that such a condition would, given the following values in the "musician" member:

```
Clarence "Gatemouth" Brown
Merle Travis
Eddie Van Halen
Rory Gallagher
Elvin Bishop
Eric Clapton
Jimi Hendrix
Stevie Ray Vaughan
Robin Trower
Ritchie Blackmore
Carlos Santana
Mark Knopfler
Pete Anderson
```

...and the following LINQ query:

```
private readonly List<Musician> musicians = new List<Musician>();
. . .
public IEnumerable<Musician> Get(string musician)
{
    IEnumerable<Musician> Musicians = from m in musicians
                                      where m.musician >= musician
                                      select m;
    . . .
```

...with "Robin" passed as the "musician" arg, return an IEnumerbale collection of Musician containing those records with a musician value of:

```
Robin Trower
Rory Gallagher
Stevie Ray Vaughan
```

(IOW, anything "greater than" Robin, such as what would appear from "Robin" onwards if using an "ORDER BY MUSICIAN" clause in a SQL query).

Instead of that working as expected, though, it doesn't even compile, and I get, "Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'" on the "where m.musician >= musician" portion of the LINQ query.

So how can I use LINQ to filter a collection of "records" by a string value?

Comment: You can use `string.Compare(m.musician, musician) >= 0` but it will remain a little dodgy. I'm not even sure about the SQL translation.

Comment: If Musician is a class, you need to override the operator >=.

Comment: @LuizFelipe No, he's comparing strings, not `Musician` objects.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry lack of attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use String.Compare(str1, str2) which returns:

- Less than zero if str1 is smaller than str2
- Greater than zero if str1 is bigger than str2
- 0 it str1 equals str2

[Here is the link to the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
    var musicians = new List<string>()
    {
        "Clarence \"Gatemouth\" Brown",
        "Merle Travis",
        "Eddie Van Halen",
        "Rory Gallagher",
        "Elvin Bishop",
        "Eric Clapton",
        "Jimi Hendrix",
        "Stevie Ray Vaughan",
        "Robin Trower",
        "Ritchie Blackmore",
        "Carlos Santana",
        "Mark Knopfler",
        "Pete Anderson",
    };

    var musician = "Robin";
    var newMusicians = musicians.Where(m => 0 < String.Compare(m,  musician));

    MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, newMusicians.ToArray()));
```

Or if you prefer sql-like syntax:

```
var newMusicians = from m in musicians
                where 0 < String.Compare(m, musician)
                select m;
```

Comment: Wouldn't the where portion of the sql-like syntax have to be actually:
where 0 < String.Compare(m.musician, musician)
?

Comment: @ClayShannon In your case yes, indeed. But as you didn't provide your Musician class I improvised and run it on a simple list of strings. The snipped I provided compiles and gives a desired result though. With that slight modification you mentioned it'll give you exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for something like the following, which finds a given substring anywhere in search string. It does not, however, search each possible substring of the search criteria string.

```
IEnumerable<Musician> Musicians = musicians.Where(m => m.IndexOf(musician, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

Comment: This *doesn't* find  substring within a string.  This is looking to see if any of the characters exist, whereas a substring would be verifying that all of the characters exist in order.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newList = myList.OrderBy(m => m).Where(m => string.Compare(m, "Robin") > 0);
```

where myList is your list of string values.

Answer (score 1):

You can use String.Compare in your LINQ query like this:

```
IEnumerable<Musician> Musicians = from m in musicians
                                          where String.Compare(m.musician, musician) > 0
                                          select m;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var Musicians = MusicianList
          .Where(m => string.Compare(m.musician, musician) >= 0)
          .OrderBy(m=>m.musician);
```

returns your desired results

Answer (score 1):

Replace your query with this:

```
IEnumerable<Musician> Musicians = from m in musicians
                                  where string.Compare(m.musician, musician, true) > 0
                                  select m;
```